# Symfony - How to use JavaScript variable to be a parameter value in Symfony route?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

**Note:** I can't install FOSJsRoutingBundle because of our company's restrictions.

**Scenario:** I have a twig template that shows a table of registered users in my database. There are buttons that corresponds to every user. Each button has a function of updating and deleting user. I'm now working on the delete user button.

**Problem:** My problem is, how to use JavaScript variable to be a parameter value in Symfony route? **e.g.**

**This path:**    `{{ path('route_to_deleteUser', { 'id': user.id }) }}`

**Change to this example path in Ajax:**

```
var userId = $(this).attr('id');
var route = "{{ path('route_to_deleteUser', { 'id': userId }) }}";
```

I tried it out but it doesn't do anything. I also tried doing this:

```
var route = "{{ path('route_to_deleteUser', { 'id': 10 }) }}"; // 10 is the value of user with id = 10
```

The code above is successful in deleting the user with the id = 10 but it only deletes the id I manually inputted in the path and also it only shows the SWAL success message but not reloading the page to show the new users table without the deleted user.

**Goal:** I want to have a button that executes a SWAL confirmation message for my deleteUser function and after the success message, it returns the new users table with the updated Database.

**This is my Route:**

```
fos_user_deleteUser:
path:      /users/{id}
defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Profile:deleteUser }
```

**This is my Controller:**

```
public function deleteUserAction($id)
    {
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->findUserBy(['id' => $id]);

        if ($user ==  null) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('User not found for user' . $user);
        }

        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

        $userManager->deleteUser($user);

        $this->setFlash('user_deleted', $user . ' has been successfully deleted!');

        $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_userList'); 

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }
```

**This is my twig:**

```
<tbody>
    {% for user in user %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.roles[0] }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.lastLogin | date('F m, Y') }}</td>
            <td class="row clearfix js-sweetalert">
                {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                    <center>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning waves-effect" data-type="update-user"><i class="material-icons">supervisor_account</i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" data-type="delete-user" id="{{ user.id }}"><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i></button>
                    </div>
                    </center>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

**This is my script:**

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('.js-sweetalert button').on('click', function () {
                var type = $(this).data('type');
                if (type === 'delete-user') {
                    var userId = $(this).attr('id');
                    showDeleteUserMessage();
                }
            });
        });
        function showDeleteUserMessage(userId) {
            swal({
                title: "Delete this user?",
                text: "You will not be able to recover this user",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#dd6b55",
                confirmButtonText: "Delete",
                closeOnConfirm: false
            }, function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "{{ path('fos_user_deleteUser', { 'id': userId }) }}",
                        success: function() {
                            swal("Success", "The user has been removed from the Database!", "success");
                        }
                    });
                } else {}
            });
        }
    </script>
```

**Feel free to edit the question and content for correction.**

I hope someone could help me and also replies when asked. My previous question has no reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about passing the `url` as an `data` attribute for each rows and collect in js. This way you don't have to build the `url` in javascript.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" data-type="delete-user" id="{{ user.id }}" data-href="{{ path('fos_user_deleteUser', { 'id': user.id }) }}">
    <i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
</button>
```

In twig, before you add js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var user_list_url = "{{ path('route_to_user_listing') }}";
</script>
```

**Why you need above code?**
So that:

- Any change to url path `/users` in your route is respected.
- `/` might be tricky when your site will be loaded from a subfolder.

And then, collect the respective url in javascript.

```
$(function () {
        $('.js-sweetalert button').on('click', function () {
            var type = $(this).data('type');
            if (type === 'delete-user') {
                var userId = $(this).attr('id'); // you might need an id somewhere.
                var deleteUrl = $(this).data('href');
                showDeleteUserMessage(userId, deleteUrl);
            }
        });
    });
    function showDeleteUserMessage(userId, deleteUrl) {
        swal({
            title: "Delete this user?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this user",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#dd6b55",
            confirmButtonText: "Delete",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }, function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: deleteUrl,
                    success: function() {
                        swal("Success", "The user has been removed from the Database!", "success");
                        window.location.href = user_list_url;
                    }
                });
            } else {}
        });
    }
```

For me it always works.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It successfully deleted the target user the same with the solution I posted where I manually inputted the user id in the route, but still, it doesn't reload the page to the new updated users table and also some of my dropdown buttons in my page won't work now. Can you refine your code?

Comment: To reload the page, you can simply add a `location.href` or `window.location.href` (code updated) in javascript. To fix your dropdown issues, you have to debug it from `console`, see what `JS` error you have there.

Comment: That's what I did. Now, I transferred it to it's own external script (mySweetAlert.js). It's not affecting other dropdown buttons now but still, the problem of not reloading the page to the new updated users table without the deleted user is not fix.

Comment: Did you integrate `window.location.href` ? 
If you did, Do you see correct path for reload in source of the page before you click on delete button?

Comment: I tried both `location.href` and `window.location.href` but it returns this error, `No route found for "GET /%7B%7B%20path('fos_user_userList')%20%7D%7D" (from "http://localhost:8000/users")`

Comment: YES! I finally found the answer! :D

... `window.location.href = '/users'; // where /users is the path to the users table`

... @Jeet, edit your answer with that updated redirection code so I can accept your answer. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Yeah, you are adding twig variable in external JS. Please assign  "{{ path('route_to_user_listing') }}" to a `JS` variable in twig file before you include `mySweetAlert.js` and then access that variable in `location.href`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154862/discussion-between-washichawbachaw-and-jeet).